# Capturar valor selecionado no checkbox do grid

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Olá, tenho o formulário acima onde mostra todos os produtos que tenho cadastrado no meu banco de dados e apresenta em um Gride.

Coloquei dentro deste Gride a opção de selecionar (checkbox). Gostaria que gravasse somente os itens que estão com "checked" do checkbox. Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Cara, explica melhor tua ideia. Edite sua pergunta e conte-nos o que você já tentou, coloque o código que já tens. Desse jeito que está sua pergunta será fechada por não ser clara o suficiente.

Comment: Veja se ajuda @jbueno

Comment: Já melhorou, você só quer isso? Salvar e o resto você já tem pronto?

Comment: Sim, eu até tenho outros grids aqui, mas sem o "check box"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apesar da resposta aceita, ela pode conter null e ao acessar o value dela dar um **NullReferenceException**, eu alteraria sua implementação de checar o valor boleano do checkbox para

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxCell cell;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow linha in dgView.Rows)
            {
              cell = linha.Cells["nome da coluna (ou o índice)"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell;// linha.Cells["nomeDaColuna"] ou linha.Cells[0]
              bool bChecked = (null != cell && null != cell.Value && true == (bool)cell.Value);
              if (bChecked)
              {
              }
           }
```

Comment: Cara, estava com esse erro de null que comentou. Coloquei o código que me enviou, resolveu. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom que ajudou. É sempre bom checá-lo se é null, já que pode assumir 3 valores null, true e false.

Comment: Só um detalhe, é **NullReferenceException**, **NullPointerException** é no Java.

Comment: valeu @jbueno corrigi esse detalhe

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa passar por todas as linhas no `DataGridView` e verificar se o `CheckBox` está marcado, desta forma

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow linha in dgView.Rows){ // passar por todas as linhas do dg
    var cell = linha.Cells["ColunaDoCheckBox"] as DataGridViewCheckBoxCell; //pegar a celula que tem o checkbox

    if((bool)cell.Value){ //verificar se está marcado
         //salvar registro
    }
}
```

Comment: Irei testar essa solução. Agradeço!

Comment: Amigo, o comando row.Cells diz que não existe. Será que é este mesmo?

Answer (score 2):

Um exemplo de como pegar os valores marcados no **checkbox**:

```
List<int> codigos = new List<int>();

    if (bool.Parse(DataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[2].FormattedValue.ToString()) == true)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow check in DataGridView.Rows)
        {
            if ((bool)check.Cells[2].FormattedValue)
            {
                b = int.Parse(check.Cells[0].Value.ToString());                                               
            }
        }

        codigos.Add(b); 
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Selecione um item");
```

Retorna os códigos do itens selecionados no **checkbox**.

Tirei [daqui](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/db6fa94a-86f7-4200-82f6-01027e297595/pegar-valor-do-checkbox-na-grid?forum=vscsharppt).

Veja mais informações de como manipular o *checkbox no grid* [aqui](http://www.macoratti.net/11/12/c_chkgv.htm).

Answer (score 0):

```
//dataGridView1 coloca o nome do seu Objeto dataGrid
foreach (DataGridViewRow Linha in dataGridView1.Rows)//Percorre o dataGrid e joga valor em 
{
    if (bool.Parse(Linha.Cells[0].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))//Pega os valores com checkbox clicados (TRUE)
    {
     MessageBox.Show("Resultado: " + Linha.Cells[2].Value);//Faca a funcao.
    }
}
```